# Convert base64 image data to png?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using [Mapbox's Javascript PBF library](https://github.com/mapbox/pbf) to convert a `PBF` file to a `png`. For context, here's what I have so far:

```
var pbfFile = new pbf(fs.readFileSync('0.pbf')), // pbfFile.buf gives us the binary data for the image

buffer = new Uint8Array();
buffer = pbfFile.readBytes();

console.log("Raw Uint8 data: " + buffer);

var bufferToBase64 =btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, buffer));

console.log("Image data in base64: " + bufferToBase64);
```

which outputs the following:

```
Raw Uint8 data: 139,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,157,86,123,84,84,199,25,223,111,230,238,222,185,23,88,150,187,168,184,32,44,23

Image data in base64: iwgAAAAAAAADnVZ7VFTHGd9v5u7euRdYlruouCAsFw==
```

I'm a little lost as to how I can convert the base64 data to a `png` image and pass it to my server. I have an `express` server running and listening to requests, right now the above code runs when I connect to it via terminal.

Is there a way I can convert the above base 64 and send the image to my browser? Not necessarily in a canvas, just as a file (thus prompting a download) is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using base64-img

Install it using npm

```
npm install base64-img --save
```

Example

```
base64Img.img('data:image/png;base64,...', 'dest', '1', function(err, filepath) {});
```

Further documentation can be found here [base64-img](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-img)